# ObservableList listener doesn't work

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am writing an application with a GUI, and I need to put `List` from `Model` package in `ListView` in GUI package.

This lists is changing during program execution. At the beggining `List` is empty, but with some time it has some elements, but the `ListView` is not updated. I can't find anything which could fix my problem. I am a begginer in GUI applications and I put this code in `start(Stage primaryStage)` method, if it could be source of my problem?

```
ListView<String> currentRank = new ListView<>();
currentRank.setPrefSize(100,100);
ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableList(EndRace.getRankList());
currentRank.setItems(items);
items.addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> c) {
        System.out.println("list changed");
        currentRank.setItems(items);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `JavaFX` your model should be composed of properties and observable collections. I guess that you have a model that doesn't do that, you try to 'wrap' your model into JavaFX stuff when needed, but unfortunately that doesn't work. If you add remove items to the standard Java collections list the wrapped observable list is never called because the standard Java collections list isn't observable...

Basically, your `EndRace.getRankList()` should return *the* `ObservableList`. Initially in your `EndRace` class you create a empty observable list and add your items to that list. Luckily `ObservableList` is a `List` so it will not mess other stuff up. Then you add and remove items to that observable list.

```
package model;

public class EndRace {
      private ObservableList<String> rankList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

      public ObservableList<String> getRankList() {
           return rankList;
      }
 } 

package gui;
...
ListView<String> currentRank = new ListView(endRace.getRankList()));
```

(btw I removed the `static` access to `EndRace`, use dependency injection instead, but in the end that is up to you)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ListProperty` and bind the `itemsProperty()` of the `ListView`:

```
ListView<String> currentRank = new ListView<>();     
ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


ListProperty<String> listProperty = new SimpleListProperty<>(items);


currentRank.itemsProperty().bindBidirectional(listProperty);

listProperty.addListener((observable, oldList, newList) -> {
    System.out.println("list changed");
    //no need to call setItems() anymore as they are binded.
    //currentRank.setItems(items);
});
```

> I am a begginer in GUI applications and I put this code in
>   start(Stage primaryStage) method, if it could be source of my problem?

Generally the code in `start()` should only be things that gets your application up and running.